# What algebraic equation could you use to solve this problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

*Tom and Mary run around the track in the same direction at the same time. Tom runs one lap in 2 minutes and 30 seconds while Mary runs it at 2 minutes and 15 seconds. If they both start at 8:30 AM, at what time will they be side-by-side again?*

My teachers tells me that the answer is **8:52:30** **AM** but I can't figure out he reached this anwer. They two times have an LCM of 2.25 x 2.5 = 5.625 minutes but adding 5.625 minutes to 8:30 AM would give 8:35 AM; not 8:52.

Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom takes 150 seconds and Mary takes 135 seconds. So clearly mary is faster. They will meet next time when Mary has been completed one extra lap .

SO answer is

lcm(150,135) seconds here lcm is lowest common multiple
$$=1350 seconds $$
0r $$=22minutes30seconds$$

Comment: But the LCM is 5.625 minutes like I said in the question. Adding the LCM to 8:30AM doesn't give the right answer.

Comment: You made a mistake calculating try again it's 1350.

Comment: But 2.25 minutes x 2.5 minutes = 5.625 minutes. No?

Comment: $150=15.10 $, $135=15.9$ So clearly lcm is $$15.9.10=1350$$

Comment: @brainkid do you know defination of lcm?.You don't directly multiply numbers to get it It's easy to calculate by seconds. If you want to do it by minutes which is in fraction then solve$$2.25m=2.5n$$where m, n are integers(lowest).Here in your caalculation$ \frac{5.625}{2.5}$ is not integer.

Comment: Ah. I get it now. The LCM is $$ 2 * 3^3 * 5^2 = 1350 seconds$$ . 1350/60 = 22.5 minutes. 8:30 AM + 22.5 minutes = 8:52:30 AM.  Thanks for keeping your answer simple!! :)

Answer (score 0):

We have

- for Tom: $s_T=v_Tt$
- for Mary: $s_M=v_Mt$

and we are looking for

$$\Delta s = s_M-s_T =v_Mt^*-v_Tt^*=\text{one lap}\implies t^*=\frac{\text{one lap}}{v_M-v_T}$$

and since "one lap" $= v_T\cdot 150=v_M\cdot 135$, we obtain

$$t^*=\frac{v_T\cdot 150}{v_M-v_T}=\frac{v_T\cdot 150}{\frac{150}{135}v_T-v_T}=1350 \:(s)$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I meant "one lap"!

Comment: How would the change in position Δs give me the time they meet? I think you're overcomplicating the answer. This is an Algebra middle school problem. Not a physics problem.

Comment: @brainkid Sorry I wasn't aware about it. Anyway, we know that one lap $= v_T\cdot 150=v_M\cdot 135$ then from my last equation we can obtain easily the result.

Answer (score 0):

If they cover $m,n$ respectively where $(m,n)=1$

$150m=135n$

$\dfrac{9n}{10}=m$ which is an integer

So, $10$ must divide $n$

$\implies n=10$ as $(m,n)=1$

So, the time $=10\cdot135$ seconds

Comment: Where did you get the 9/10 from?

Comment: @brainkid, By dividing both sides by $$(135,150)=?$$

Comment: But there's no t anywhere for time. We're solving for time.

Comment: @brankin, $135n=150m$ is minimum required time. That's why they have been equated

Answer (score 0):

After $t$ seconds, Tom and Mary have made $\dfrac t{150}$ and $\dfrac t{135}$ laps, and these ratios differ by $1$. Hence

$$t=\frac1{\dfrac1{135}-\dfrac1{150}}=1350\,\text{sec}=22\,\text{min}\,30\ \text{sec}.$$

Comment: You don't need an LMC to solve this.

Comment: How did you know that $$t=\frac1{\dfrac1{135}-\dfrac1{150}}?$$

Comment: This comes from the first sentence.

Comment: But why are you dividing 1 by the subtracted fractions?

Comment: Turn the first sentence into an equation and solve it. You will see.